# php adds my numbers to 10^-16 instead of ZERO (0)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that adds a lot of numbers with decimals.... FLOAT numbers from MySQL DB.

Right now, I have the issue that sometimes they will add to ridiculously small numbers like -1.11022302463E-16, instead of zero.  Any ideas?

By the way, 
All my numbers I'm adding are monetary, so they are all like : XXX.XX  ....

Thanks

Comment: If you're storing decimal numbers (i.e. monetary values), why aren't you using the `DECIMAL` data type?

Comment: Ummmm... I don't know.  ha!  I am using float(10,2), because that's what the previous programmer used.... is it stupid?  Can I literally just go change all the DB columns to DECIMAL?

Comment: You can alter the table to add a decimal column, copy the values over, make sure they tally (you're copying floats after all), then safely remove the old float column when you're done. That doesn't really stop PHP from handling floats like floats, but it's a start.

Comment: Just don't use PHP for scientific calculations.

Comment: @ahmet, he's using PHP for money calculation, but you're right it's unsuited for that as well :-).

Comment: @bolt thanks.  This is still a dev environment, so I don't mind just changing straight to DECIMAL(10,2), after a backup copy of course.

Comment: Many companies having problems with computations in PHP. They develop RPC tools like Thrift to do calculations in some other language. For example Java has a `fpstrict` keyword that forces IEEE 754 standards in floating point computation.

Comment: @ahmet, well for me, I think my fix is not too bad, and I really don't care about a penny... so I can do some rounding and make it work I suppose.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @BoltClock, change all the `float` fields to `decimal(10,2)` fields in your database **where** they are used for monetary values. 
Float suffers from rounding problems like the ones you describe.

If you do all your adding **inside** the database you will not suffer any rounding errors.

You can add numbers by doing a

```
UPDATE table1 SET money1 = money1 + 10.20 WHERE table1.id = 10
```

Substituting the constants for parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately trying to add in my SQL statement would be pretty outrageous, it's tallying things from all over the place.. but thanks for the tip.  I'll code in a little safe guard as well: `if($runningTotal > -.001 && $runningTotal < 0)...`

Comment: @SQL is very good at getting stuff from `all over the place` together so that should be no reason. May I suggest asking a question `how do I do ... in SQL using ....`

Answer (score 1):

read this section of the php manual, especially the precision warning.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

at the bottom you will see links to functions you can use for high precision math